# Real-time web application using Redis key-value store

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor, redis, firebase

I'm a web developer and used to using FireBase for a lot of my projects. Much of the work is already done out-of-the box there regarding realtime synchronization etc. In my next project, however, I'm not allowed to use an external provider for storing data, and as there's no way to host Firebase on a local server, it's out of the question.

For that project, currently a Redis key-value store is used. I know Redis also supports a pub-sub model, and I'm searching for a good way to use this Redis key-value store in a realtime web application. I've found a Meteor library (https://github.com/meteor/redis-livedata), which looks promising. I'm used to using AngularJS, however. And the majority of the solutions I found only use Redis for the pub-sub model, and not for the datastore (maybe for good reason). I've found an alternative which uses Django as the datastore (https://github.com/mburst/django-realtime-tutorial). I've also come across Firehose (http://firehose.io), but this doesn't use the Redis key-value store either.

Does anyone know a good way to emulate the same functionality Firebase provides, using a Redis key-value store, preferably compatible with AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction -  Django is a python based web framework, not a datastore .
For your requirement , tools like [deployd](http://www.deployd.com) and [loopback](http://loopback.io/) suit alot.
They are opensource versions of services like Firebase or Parsed.

Both of them work with javascript(nodejs) and hence would support AngularJS or any other framework you would want to use.
For datastore backend, most preferred pluggable backend is mongodb as it supports fast writes, rich querying, and persistence of data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's very useful! Is there one you can recommend (in terms of support, developer base,...) over the other?